# error on every sql query with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I created a new empty php file with simple function for mysqli query, like this:

```
$dab = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPassword,$dbDBName);

function dbq($sql) {
    global $dab;
    $wynik= $dab->query($sql);
    if (!$wynik) {


        printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $dab->error);

    }
    return $wynik;
}
dbq('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
dbq('SET collation_connection = utf8_general_ci');
```

On every query I'm getting blank Errormessage and really don't know what could be a cause here.

Script is connecting with the database without any errors. When I performed a looped query, I recieved blank Errormessage for each repeat.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting back

Comment: There is none. $dab->error is empty.

Comment: did you verify that $dab is not null, or rather $dab->connect_errno is false

Comment: First include your db details inside your function and try again.

Comment: my bad, there is "access denied" within connect_error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You ought to set proper PHP error reporting in order to see PHP errors
2. You have to verify connect errors.
3. You shouldn't echo errors out unconditionally.
4. Oh, and you have to set charset using the right method

So, the code would be

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

$dab = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUser,$dbPassword,$dbDBName);
if ( !$dab )
{
    throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error());
}
if (!$dab->set_charset('utf8')) {
    throw new Exception($dab->error);
}

function dbq($sql) {
    global $dab;
    $wynik= $dab->query($sql);
    if (!$wynik) {
        throw new Exception($dab->error);
    }
    return $wynik;
}
```